# Set Java Swing Dock Icon on Mac

Tags: java, macos, swing

I'm new to the Java Swing Package and I am trying to build a basic application. I want to change the *dock icon on MacOS* from the basic Java logo to my own and I tried using the code below but nothing changes. And this is the [dock icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF8Eh.png). I'm using MacOS 12.0.1 and Java SE 17.

```
var image = new ImageIcon("Content.png");
frame.setIconImage(image.getImage());
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: [Search Stack Overflow](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+mac+app+icon&t=ipad&ia=web) before posting.

Comment: [*jpackage*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/392) tool is likely the modern approach.